# Place a div pop up just below the input box through javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this input box:

```
<input type='text' size='2' name='action_qty' onmouseup='showHideChangePopUp()'>
```

and the div pop-up:

```
<div id='div_change_qty' name='div_change_qty' style='display:none;width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute;z-index:10;background:darkgray' >
    <table width='100%' height='100%'>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Increase</td></tr>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Decrease</td></tr>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Move Items</td></tr>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Change Status</td></tr>
    </table>    
</div>
```

The javascript function is as follows:

```
function showHideChangePopUp(e){

        //alert('here')
        if ( event.clientX ) { // Grab the x-y pos.s if browser is IE.
            CurrentLeft = event.clientX + document.body.scrollLeft;
            CurrentTop  = event.clientY + document.body.scrollTop;
        }
        else {  // Grab the x-y pos.s if browser isn't IE.
            CurrentLeft = e.pageX ;
            CurrentTop  = e.pageY ;
        }  
        //if ( CurrentLeft < 0 ) { CurrentLeft = 0; };
        //if ( CurrentTop  < 0 ) { CurrentTop  = 0; };  

        document.getElementById('div_change_qty').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('div_change_qty').style.top = CurrentTop ;
        document.getElementById('div_change_qty').style.left = CurrentLeft ;

        return true;
    }
```

On click inside the input box, I need to place this div popup just below the input box. The above function places the div wherever we click inside the input box, but not at the bottom of the input box, which is what i want. How can i change the JS function to do the required task.

Comment: javascript or jquery ?

Comment: can you post the JavaScript you have at the moment? The showHideChangePopUp() method

Comment: MY problem is actually placing it just below the input box ie. dynamically we should find the position of the particular input box and place the div just below it. Most of the answers give answers to hide and show of div which is not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

We all misinterpreted your original post as *how* to show or hide the div.

Here's the code to put the div directly below the input box, by using the [getClientRects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.getClientRects) of the input element:

```js
function showHideChangePopUp(e){
  var div= document.querySelector('#div_change_qty');
  var inp= document.querySelector('#action_qty');
  var rect= inp.getClientRects();
  div.style.display= 'block';
  div.style.left= rect[0].left+'px';
  div.style.top= rect[0].bottom+'px';
}
```

```html
<div id='div_change_qty' name='div_change_qty' style='display:none;width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute;z-index:10;background:darkgray' >
  <table width='100%' height='100%'>
    <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Increase</td></tr>
    <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Decrease</td></tr>
    <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Move Items</td></tr>
    <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Change Status</td></tr>
  </table>
</div>

<input type='text' size='2' name='action_qty' id="action_qty" onmouseup='showHideChangePopUp()'>
```

---

**Original Post**

It's usually best to avoid JavaScript within your HTML.

The following attaches an `onmouseup` handler to the input, which toggles the display of the div.

It also attaches an `onblur` handler, so that the div disappears once you leave the input box.

```js
var qty= document.querySelector('#qty');

qty.onmouseup= function(e) {
  var div= document.querySelector('#div_change_qty');
  div.style.display= div.style.display==='block'?'none':'block';
}

qty.onblur= function(e) {
  var div= document.querySelector('#div_change_qty');
  div.style.display= 'none';
}
```

```css
#div_change_qty{display:none;}
```

```html
<input type='text' size='2' name='action_qty' id="qty">

<div id='div_change_qty' name='div_change_qty' style='display:none;width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute;z-index:10;background:darkgray' >
    <table width='100%' height='100%'>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Increase</td></tr>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Decrease</td></tr>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Move Items</td></tr>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Change Status</td></tr>
    </table>    
</div>

<input>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using JQuery

```
function showHideChangePopUp(){
    $(this).after($("#div_change_qty").html());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Likt this ?

```js
function showHideChangePopUp(){
  document.getElementById('div_change_qty').style.display='block'?'block':'none';
  
  }
```

```css
#div_change_qty{display:none;}
```

```html
<input type='text' size='2' name='action_qty' onmouseup='showHideChangePopUp()'>

<div id='div_change_qty' name='div_change_qty' style='display:none;width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute;z-index:10;background:darkgray' >
    <table width='100%' height='100%'>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Increase</td></tr>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Decrease</td></tr>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Move Items</td></tr>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Change Status</td></tr>
    </table>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I improved on Billy's answer so that the div appears `onfocus` and disappears `onblur`. Provided two versions: pure Js and jQuery.

```js
function showHideChangePopUp(m) {
    var disp = m === 'hide' ? 'none' : 'block';
    document.getElementById('div_change_qty').style.display = disp;
}
function showHideChangePopUpjQ(m) {
    var disp = m === 'hide' ? 'none' : 'block';
    $('#div_change_qty').css("display", disp);
}
```

```css
#div_change_qty{display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>With pure JS</p>
<input type='text' size='2' name='action_qty' onfocus='showHideChangePopUp("show")' onblur='showHideChangePopUp("hide")'>
<p>With jQuery</p>
<input type='text' size='2' name='action_qty' onfocus='showHideChangePopUpjQ("show")' onblur='showHideChangePopUp("hide")'>

<div id='div_change_qty' name='div_change_qty' style='display:none;width:200px;height:200px;position:absolute;z-index:10;background:darkgray' >
    <table width='100%' height='100%'>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Increase</td></tr>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Decrease</td></tr>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Move Items</td></tr>
        <tr><td width='20%'></td><td>Change Status</td></tr>
    </table>    
</div>
```